# SDWebImageSwiftUI - How to show default image before user selection

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a profile picture that I am attempting to show a default image until a user selects a picture from a picker (say that three times fast). In WebImage, I point to a view Model, which connects to my database to grab the user image. If no image exists I currently just have it on an empty string.

For reference, this is the line that serves up the image

> WebImage(url: URL(string: vm.userModel?.profilePictureURL ?? "")

I tried adding a bool that updated on the onChange function to true and tried wrapping the webImage in an IF statement, but the view didn't update correctly.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
struct ProfilePicture: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = DashboardLogic()
    
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
  
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .topTrailing){
            VStack{
                if let inputImage = inputImage {
                    Image(uiImage: inputImage)
                     .resizable()
                     .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                     .frame(width:150, height: 150)
                     .clipShape(Circle())
                     
                 } else{
                         WebImage(url: URL(string: vm.userModel?.profilePictureURL ?? ""))
                             .resizable()
                             .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                             .frame(width:150, height: 150)
                             .clipShape(Circle())
        
                 }
                    
                Button(action: {
                    showingImagePicker = true
                }){
                    Image(systemName:("plus.circle.fill"))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonTwo"))
                        .frame(width:30, height:25)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
               
            //PRESENT PICKER
        }
            
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker){
                EditorImagePicker(image: $inputImage)
                
            }
            
    }
        //SAVE IMAGE TO DATABASE (FIREBASE)
        .onChange(of: inputImage, perform: { _ in
            persistImageToStorage() //call to save function
        })
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: WebImage(url: URL(string: vm.userModel?.profilePictureURL ?? ""),placeHolder: ?)

Comment: Yup, this answered it. Can't believe i overlooked it. Placed the placeholder after the WebImage as .placeholder, but you still put me on the right path. Thanks!